# Integral on a positive closed contour

Tags: integration

If $\gamma$ is a closed positive oriented closed contour how can I prove that

$$\int_\gamma \frac{\sin{z}}{z}\,\mathrm{d}z = 0?$$

Comment: What theorems do you think might be relevant here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let$$F(z)=1-\frac{z^2}{3!}+\frac{z^4}{5!}-\cdots$$Then $F$ is analytic and $F(z)=\dfrac{\sin z}z$ when $z\neq0$. Since the domain of $F$ is $\mathbb C$ (that is, $F$ is an entire function), it follows from Cauchy's integral theorem that $\int_Cf(z)\,\mathrm dz=0$.